# How to run defined sbt.Command from build.sbt file?

Tags: scala, command, sbt

I am using one of sbt plugins that has an object of sbt.Command defined:

```
val xCommand: Command = Command(xCommandKey)(_ => xParser) { (st, args) => ... }
```

I need to run it from build.sbt file and have no idea how to do that.
Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

Sbt-files are shorthand for defining configuration. To mix in general scala code you need to add ie. Build.scala into the project directory.

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Full-Def.html#Relating+build.sbt+to+Build.scala to understand how these files cooperate.